# Problema con Modo oscuro Android, background no aplica los cambios

Tags: java, android, android-studio, aplicación-movil

estoy programando una app en Android Studio y al poner el modo oscuro todo cambia excepto el background. Es decir, cuando el usuario active el modo oscuro en su teléfono y entre en la app, el fondo de esta cambie a otra imagen para así adaptarse.

Comment: Bienvenido,,revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar este enlace https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme?hl=es.
Es de la documentacion oficial de android devs.